# Increasing timeout for mod_proxy_ajp connections

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat, ajp, mod-proxy-ajp

I've got my apache (2.2.3) talking to tomcat 6.something through mod_proxy_ajp.

I have some ridiculously long lived requests (2-6 minutes) and I think we're hitting some default timeout somewhere... where is the correct place to bump that up?

here is my proxy def:

```
<Location /blah>
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8010/blah
  ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8010/blah
</Location>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't say I've tried this, but I was interested in the question, so I did a bit of googling around and found [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout):

---

#### ProxyTimeout directive

This directive allows a user to specifiy a timeout on proxy requests. This is useful when you have a slow/buggy appserver which hangs, and you would rather just return a timeout and fail gracefully instead of waiting however long it takes the server to return.

---

The default value is the value of the Timeout directive, which in turn defaults to 300 seconds.  So try bumping up ProxyTimeout and see if it helps.

P.S.  Keep in mind that Tomcat might have its own timeout(s), too.  [This document](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html) has some more information (although, keep in mind, I don't have personal experience with these settings).

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like to change the timeout just for the ajp proxy and not globally you can add the "timeout" parameter, like so:

```
<Location /blah>
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8010/blah timeout=600
  ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8010/blah
</Location>
```