# Is there a connection timeout setting between Apache and JBoss?

Tags: apache-2.2, timeout, gateway, jboss

We’re using JBoss 7.1.3.Final with Apache 2.2.31.  We’re connecting from Apache to JBoss through an AJP connection.  We are noticing 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT errors after 60 seconds when requesting a particular page that does a lot of processing.  We have set this parameter in our /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file

```
Timeout 300
```

However, even after restarting Apache, we are still seeing the timeouts.  What other settings do I need to examine in order to increase the timeout?  There does not seem to be any relevant connection timeout settings within our JBoss standalone.xml configuration file.

When I connect to JBoss directly (by-passing Apache), I notice I don’t see these timeout errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing timeout for mod\_proxy\_ajp connections](http://serverfault.com/questions/10525/increasing-timeout-for-mod-proxy-ajp-connections)

Comment: In which interface is listening jboss? which port? It's the same interface that your apache ajp conecction? Is Jboss listening in all interfaces? Maybe the iptables works wrong?

Comment: IMHO you should investigate why it takes so much first, if you're hosting a website 60 seconds in unacceptable, you'll DOS yourself this way, users get bored after ~15seconds waiting and click again, so you have an amplification of requests

Comment: @Fredi -- this is not a user facing page.  This is an admin page and the three people that will use it all udnerstand why it takes so long to generate the ouptut.

Comment: @yoonix, I changed a line in my ajx_proxy pass file to "ProxyPass /mydir/ ajp://localhost:8009/mydir/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300" but I'm still getting a timeout after 60 seconds.

Comment: How are the iptables related to the timeout settings?  If the iptables/ports were wrong, I wouldn't be able to make any connections at all to JBoss, but everything is running fine -- the only problem is when a request takes a long time, the data does not get served back to the client.

Comment: What kind of request are you reverse proxying to JBOSS?
GET/POST? Maybe 60 seconds is the idle timeout you have configured for JBOSS request processing threads?

Comment: Also when a request times out, is it logged in botrh the apache access logs and the jboss access logs?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use proxy_http_module instead of proxy_ajp_module.
That change has resolved the same issue  I was facing.